# com.jayway.jsonpath.InvalidPathException: Space not allowed in path

Tags: java, json, jsonpath, json-path-expression, jayway

I'm using [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) to check matches of some `json-paths` against a `JSON` document with a `SpringBoot` application.

It gives the following exception when I include `in` operator inside the expression. But the same `jsonpath` expression works fine [online](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/). 
I tried debug inside `jayway` code as well but had no luck in finding a resolution.

```
com.jayway.jsonpath.InvalidPathException: com.jayway.jsonpath.InvalidPathException: Space not allowed in path
```

`JSON` payload:

```
{
     "color": "red",
     "price": 19.95
}
```

`jsonpath expression`:

```
$.[?(@.color in ['red','blue'])]
```

Comment: Which version of library do you use? I checked it with `2.4.0` and it works fine for given `JSON` and `path expression`.

Comment: @MichałZiober: Thanks for your response. Yes it works fine with the latest version. It was silly that I didn't try a version upgrade. (for the reference of anyone who might experience the same issue, I got the specified error with version 2.0.0)